# ¿Cómo guardar un svg generado con javascript en localhost? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, svg

verán tengo una imagen en SVG y se descarga bien, reconoce los datos, etc, mi problema es al guardarla la guarda en descargas y yo necesito guardarla en una carpeta de mi servidor, ¿me podrían ayudar por favor? :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#SVGsave').click(function(){
    var a      = document.createElement('a');
    var tmp  = document.getElementById("ex1");
    var svg = tmp.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    a.href= 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + unescape(svg.outerHTML);

    a.save='<?=base_url()?>image/<?=$u->user_id?>.svg';
    a.download = '<?=$u->user_id?>.svg';
    a.target   = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a);
    user_id ="<?=$u->user_id?>";
    image_name ="<?=$u->user_id?>.svg";
    $.post("<?=base_url()?>index.php/QR/save/<?=$u->user_id?>/<?=$u->user_id?>.svg", function(data){

    });            

    });
});
```

Comment: `y yo necesito guardarla en una carpeta de mi servidor` ¿es decir que quieres guardar tu archivo svg en otra ubicación?, en el código que has colocado, no veo qué haces para establecer la ubicación destino del archivo.

Comment: mm la guarda por default cuando pongo descargar en descargas, yo quiero guardarla en una carpeta llamada image dentro del proyecto que esta alojado en mi localhost

Comment: Si, de hecho no sé cómo ponerla, he intentado ponerla en download o en href pero no las reconoce

Comment: _Creo_ que por temas de seguridad, javascript (cliente) no tiene acceso a ubicaciones del lado servidor. Ya que PHP no es lo mío, te recomiendo ver esta [pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31605623/4092887) o busca: `php save svg in folder`. Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias y veremos que resulta :)

Comment: Como te lo comenta Mauricio, para guardar en una ubicacion del servidor tienes que hacerlo con un lenguaje del lado del servidor como PHP, Node, Java, Python, etc.

Comment: @elporfirio si ya locobseguí y tenían razón, muchas gracias, saludos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es como me decían aplicarlo con un lenguaje de lado de servidor y lo ejecuté en un controlador, utilicé la librería file de CodeIgniter

```
    //Función para guardar el QR en la carpeta de image
function save($user_id, $image_name){

    $this->user->change_userqr($user_id, $image_name);
    //mandamos a llamar el helper file para crearlo y guardarlo en la carpeta
    $this->load->helper('file');
    //Data es la información osea el xml del SVG

    $data = $this->input->POST('svg_code');
    if ( ! write_file("./image/$image_name", $data))
    {
    echo '<script>
    alert(No se pudo crear archivo);
    </script>';
}
else
{
    echo '<script>
    alert(Se creó archivo);
    </script>';
}  
    redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
}

// con esta función exportamos el zip a la carpeta Download en la plataforma seleccionada
function expo  
    $date = $this->input->POST('date');
//cargamos la librería zip y guardamos archivos de acuerdo a lo guardado en la base de datos
    $this->load->library('zip');
 for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post("img[]")); $i++)
  { 
$img[$i]=$this->input->post("img[".$i."]");
        $path[$i] = "./image/$img[$i]";
        $this->zip->read_file($path[$i], TRUE);

    }
    //De acuerdo a la plataforma lo guardo en la carpeta
    $plat = $this->input->POST('id_plat');

    switch ($plat) {
        case '1':
        $this->zip->archive("./downloads/SelfieIn/$date.zip");
        $dato['consult'] = $this->user->consult();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $dato);
        break;
        case '2':
        $this->zip->archive("./downloads/Appicultor/$date.zip");
        $dato['consult'] = $this->user->consult();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $dato);
        break;
        //Si no se hace filtro no se guarda
        default:
            echo "<script>
            alert('No filtraste');
            </script>" ;
            redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //funcion de contralor codeigniter 
    function save(){

     // $this->user->change_userqr(2, "javiersvg");
      //mandamos a llamar el helper file para crearlo y guardarlo en la carpeta
      $image_name="NumeroSvg1";
     $this->load->helper('file');
     //Data es la información osea el xml del SVG

    $data = $this->input->POST('SvgText');
    $image_name=$this->input->POST('numero_clavo');
    if ( ! write_file("C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop/$image_name.svg", $data))
    {
    echo '<script>
    alert(No se pudo crear archivo);
    </script>';
}else
     {
      echo '<script>
      alert(Se creó archivo);
      </script>';
    }  
         //redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
       }


**//codigo js**
$("#GenerarSvg").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var qrcode = new QRCode({
        content: link,
        join: true,
        container: "svg-viewbox",
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        color: "black",
        background: "white",
        ecl: "H"
      });
      
      var svg = qrcode.svg();
      
    ajaxbusquedareal("save",svg,numero_clavo);
});


function ajaxbusquedareal(opcion, SvgText,numero_clavo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "index.php/Admin/" + opcion, //comprobar que no me pase datos vacios ya que si es asi lanzo mensaje de incorrecto
        type: 'POST',
        data: { SvgText: SvgText,numero_clavo:numero_clavo },

        success: function(respuesta) {

                alert("ok"+respuesta);
         


        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
        }
    });
}

<body>
    <div class="md-content md-center">
     
        <div class="md-pos">
            <div id="qrcode" class="md-qrcode-img md-center"></div>



<form role="form" class="formulario" id="GenerarSvg" name="GenerarSvg" method="POST">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success btn-lg btn-responsive" id="Svg"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span> SVG GENERAR.</button>
</form>

            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
       var link="link/index.php/Admin/editarAdmin?get=[<?php echo $datos[0]?>]";
        var numero_clavo=<?php echo $datos[0]?>;
        
        </script>
   
        <script src="<?= base_url()?>js/generarqrv2.js">  </script>
```